# System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient - Client does not have permission to send as this sender

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, windows-authentication, smtpclient

I have a need to send an email via a web application but the address that the email goes to requires SMTP authentication. The code works for mailboxes that *don't* need authentication.

I would like to pass across Windows user credentials (the site uses Windows authentication) and thought this would be achieved with my code, but unfortunately I get errors about the client not having permission to send. I'm assuming it is using the credentials of the application pool user rather than the logged in user.

```
Dim mailMessage As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
Dim strBody As String = "<font size='2' font face='Tahoma'>" & _
"<br><br><b>Date: </b>" & Me.txtDate.Text
mailMessage.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAddress) 'Logged in user's email address
' More code here to build the email body etc... 
' Then attempt to send it:
Dim smtpClient As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage)
```

Web.config contains only the SMTP server name under `system.net` (mailsettings->smtp)

How do I get the application to use the user's credentials?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry, its asp.net!

Comment: I don't know much about ASP.NET, but perhaps the problem occurs due to that the backend code is run on the serverside, thus the server's account credentials is used? Or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: I think you need to set the credentials to [CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Andrew that looks like it may be the right way to go. I'll try it out on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify the `UseDefaultCredentials` in the Web.config? If not you must do that to use them. This will allow the currently logged in user to send email trough the specified SMTP server. Note that websites usually run under a separate user credential, not the currently logged in user on the machine.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
      <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Or specify the credentials in code.

```
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fake@false.nl", "abcd1234");
```

If both do not work you simply are not authorized to send mail on that server.

See for more info

https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/w355a94k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No I didn't put that in the web.config. I'll give that a try on Monday. Does it go in the `<mailsettings>` tag? It does need to send as the logged in user instead of an application pool user. We recently changed our Exchange servers to require authentication when sending emails to group addresses. All works fine for users who are emailing via Outlook but obviously in my application it doesn't work

Comment: If it is the current user then it should work (if the Exchange server allows it)

Comment: I can't get this to work as I won't know the user's password to create a new instance of `NetworkCredential`. Is there any way to pass it from windows authentication instead of specifying it manually?

Comment: Yes, that is using `defaultCredentials`. Do not specify them with `new NetworkCredential`